# Openssh suddenly not working on my Windows

Tags: windows, openssh, ssh-agent

I use git bash to login to open ssh server hosted in a windows machine
the command that I used is

```
ssh -D 127.0.0.1:8080 user@ssh-server -i ssh_host_rsa_key -vvv
```

---

```
OpenSSH_7.1p2, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
dsa-sha2-nistp521
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
/c/Users/zhjun/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from cn-zhjun-w10
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/c/Users/zhjun/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /c/Users/zhjun/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 10.172.18.113
debug1: Host 'cn-zhjun-w10' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /c/Users/zhjun/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: ssh_host_rsa_key (0x60006bc70), explicit
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,keyboard-interactive
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: ssh_host_rsa_key
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
debug2: input_userauth_pk_ok: fp SHA256:sZstaNxene7qmdvgfK91zjtQQ4Oeqb+aS9X7//paJo4
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA SHA256:sZstaNxene7qmdvgfK91zjtQQ4Oeqb+aS9X7//paJo4
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup keyboard-interactive
debug3: remaining preferred: password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
debug2: userauth_kbdint
debug2: we sent a keyboard-interactive packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive
debug3: userauth_kbdint: disable: no info_req_seen
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive).
```

It works the last couple months, but suddenly not working..

Answer (score 0):

Maybe yo should make sure that your public key is included in the .ssh/authorized_keys file on the destination machine.

Other way is to change the *sshd_config* file in the remote server and set *PasswordAuthentication* from **no** to **yes** and restart the ssh daemon

Comment: I've verified the first one and I've added the keys properly already and the private key is called ssh_host_rsa_key which  is the correct key pair.

Comment: If I changed no to yes I would need a password right? But I need keys to login.